Run Android applications that run WebView independently of browsers
I am working on creating Android applications written in Java that run WebView for the front end completely and the backend using Java. After a while, I found a problem when I open one of these applications Which runs WebView for the front end, and when I forcefully stop the browser, my application stops.
What is the solution to make applications work completely independently of browsers? I think it is a big problem for me because the browser may crash or suffer from a malfunction, and my applications that run WebView will stop.

run your webview in separate proccess android:process=":webview_process" this why the webview carshes will not affect the man app

Thanks for the help, but I tried it and the problem still exists


What is the solution To make applications work completely independently of browsers?

You could use an independent implementation of Web rendering, such as Mozilla's GeckoView. Note that this will significantly increase the size of your app, as you will be embedding most of a Web browser into the app.
